# Not able to get hyperledger fabric details on hyperledger explorer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer, hyperledger-explorer

I downloaded hyperledger explorer and I want to explore the blockchain network setup by [two org tutorial](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org). My config file for explorer is

```
{
 "network-config": {
    "org1": {
        "name": "peerOrg1",
        "mspid": "Org1MSP",
        "peer1": {
            "requests": "grpc://127.0.0.1:7051",
            "events": "grpc://127.0.0.1:7053",
            "server-hostname": "peer0.org1.example.com"

        },          
        "peer2": {
            "requests": "grpc://127.0.0.1:8051",
            "events": "grpc://127.0.0.1:8053",
            "server-hostname": "peer1.org1.example.com"

        },          
        "admin": {
            "key": "/home/mfgteg/fabric-samples/first-example/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/keystore",
            "cert": "/home/mfgteg/fabric-samples/first-example/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/signcerts"
        }
    },      
    "org2": {
        "name": "peerOrg2",
        "mspid": "Org2MSP",
        "peer1": {
            "requests": "grpc://127.0.0.1:9051",
            "events": "grpc://127.0.0.1:9053",
            "server-hostname": "peer0.org2.example.com"

        },          
        "peer2": {
            "requests": "grpc://127.0.0.1:10051",
            "events": "grpc://127.0.0.1:10053",
            "server-hostname": "peer1.org2.example.com"

        },          
        "admin": {
            "key": "/home/mfgteg/fabric-samples/first-example/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp/keystore",
            "cert": "/home/mfgteg/fabric-samples/first-example/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp/signcerts"
        }
    }       
 },
 "host": "localhost",
 "port": "8080",
 "channel": "mychannel",
 "keyValueStore": "/tmp/fabric-client-kvs",
 "eventWaitTime": "30000",
 "mysql": {
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": "3306",
    "database": "fabricexplorer",
    "username": "root",
    "passwd": "****"
 }
}
```

I even tried keeping the tls certificates and kept grpcs instead of grpc. On explorer window its not showing channel ,peer and block information.

Below is some part of the log :

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::8080
at Object._errnoException (util.js:1024:11)
at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1046:20)
at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1351:14)
at listenInCluster (net.js:1392:12)
at Server.listen (net.js:1476:7)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/mfgteg/blockchain-explorer/main.js:167:19)
at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
```

Answer (score 2):

EADDRINUSE :::8080 means you've already used the port for some other process.
Change the port setting in config.json file to an unused port instead, for example:
"port": "5000"
Try to start the server again.

Comment: Already did that now I am getting error "31merror[39m: [client-utils.js]: sendPeersProposal - Promise is rejected: Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: Connect Failed at new createStatusError (/home/user/blockchain-explorer/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:65:15) at /home/user/blockchain-explorer/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:568:15" and While clicking the select channel option , its not showing channel.

Answer (score 0):

This error you are seeing `Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::8080` says that you already have a process running on PORT 8080 - it might be Composer Playground.  One of the configuration files allows you to specify the port for Explorer to run on.

If you are using the 'standard' Composer Tutorial for MultiOrg then it uses **grpcs** so the those URLs need to be modified, and the tlscerts need to be added for the peers (refer to the connection.json file for those)

Comment: Ok got it .I killed the process using 8080. I am able to see peers. But again am getting error "31merror[39m: [client-utils.js]: sendPeersProposal - Promise is rejected: Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: Connect Failed
    at new createStatusError (/home/user/blockchain-explorer/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:65:15)
    at /home/user/blockchain-explorer/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:568:15" and While clicking the select channel option , its not showing channel.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced loopback ip address with localhost and it worked.

Comment: what do you mean by this exactly? You replaced `"mysql": {
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": "3306",` with `"mysql": {
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": "3306",` instead?